# Matching strftime weeks with pandas time series week frequency

Tags: python, pandas, strftime, week-number

I have a dataframe with a `'%Y/%U'` date column:

```
    Value Count       YW       Date
0             2  2017/19 2017-05-13
1             2  2017/20 2017-05-19
2            24  2017/22 2017-06-03
3            35  2017/23 2017-06-10
4            41  2017/24 2017-06-17
..          ...      ...        ...
126          51  2020/05 2020-02-06
127          26  2020/06 2020-02-15
128          30  2020/07 2020-02-22
129          26  2020/08 2020-02-29
130          18  2020/09 2020-03-04
```

I'm trying to add the missing weeks, like `2017/21` with 0 Count values, so I created this index:

```
idx = pdh.pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max(), freq='W').floor('d')
```

Which yields:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-14', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-28', '2017-06-04',
               '2017-06-11', '2017-06-18', '2017-06-25', '2017-07-02',
               '2017-07-09', '2017-07-16',
               ...
               '2019-12-29', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-19',
               '2020-01-26', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-09', '2020-02-16',
               '2020-02-23', '2020-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=147, freq=None)
```

Almost there, converting to `'%Y/%U'` again:

```
idx = idx.strftime('%Y/%U')
```

But this yields:

```
Index(['2017/20', '2017/21', '2017/22', '2017/23', '2017/24', '2017/25',
       '2017/26', '2017/27', '2017/28', '2017/29',
       ...
       '2019/52', '2020/01', '2020/02', '2020/03', '2020/04', '2020/05',
       '2020/06', '2020/07', '2020/08', '2020/09'],
      dtype='object', length=147)
```

I'm not sure yet whether it is a problem with reindexing but I've noticed that the firts year/week pair is now `2017/20` instead of `2017/19`. This is because the `freq='W'` offset converts every date to the correspondent week starting day as the default is the same as `'W-SUN'` [anchored offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). Indeed, `2017-05-14` is a Sunday.

The problem is that the converted date now returns the next week number because of this, `2017-05-13` was converted to `2017-05-14`. Using the `%U` [strftime code](https://strftime.org/) does start the weeks on Sunday as well, however it is counted from the previous Sunday. Using `'W-SAT'` (as `2017-05-13` was a Saturday) solves it at the start but the end will be wrong this case.

Is there any dynamic solution so `date_range` would start and end with the proper weeks?